# Run only an onAdd listener in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in Firestore that is constantly being updated and so has a **lot** of documents.

Now, I want to attach a collection snapshot listener such that whenever there is new data, and only when there is new data, an event is triggered.

I tried

```
CollectionReference reference = firestore.collection("table");
reference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable snapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException exception) {
        List<DocumentChange> documentChanges = (snapshots == null) ?
            new ArrayList<DocumentChange>() : snapshots.getDocumentChanges();

        for (DocumentChange document: documentChanges) {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = document.getDocument();
            DocumentChange.Type documentType = document.getType();

            if (documentType == Document.Type.ADDED) {
                Log.d("Notice", "Document added");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but it got **every** document and at a point even crashed the application because the documents. was a lot.

Can anyone help me on how to go about it. To be clear, I want to attach a document listener and listen only for document updates **after** attaching the snapshot listener

Answer (score 0):

A snapshot listener on a collection or query will always initially return the entire set of matching documents.  They will be stored in memory until the listener is removed.  There is no way to change this behavior.

Instead, consider modeling your data in such a way that gives you the ability to query only for current documents, perhaps using a date type field, and querying only for documents with a date > the current time.

Also bear in mind that you can use Cloud Functions to have some backend code trigger for only newly added documents.

Comment: Are you saying I can attach a snapshot listener to the query instead of the collection reference? Such as `Query query = firestore.collection("table").where("timestamp", "<=", System.currentTimeMillis);`

Comment: A CollectionReference actually **is** a Query.  It's a query with no filters.  See how it quite literally extends Query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference

Comment: @cr05s19xx exactly what I need